# Server side speech recognition for HTML5 applications

Tags: .net, html, speech-recognition, web-audio-api

I am running a web application which makes intensive use of WebkitSpeechRecognition which, in turn, makes use of Google's servers.

I would like to free my application from this dependence.
We already make use of WebAudio, ad the api is well supported across browsers.

Is there any suitable server-side solution (IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2) for this scenario, or any Dot Net path we  could take to build our own recognition server?

I know the question is quite broad in scope, but even after searching the web we are still quite disoriented.

Comment: I guess it's worth mentioning that there's different kinds of speech recognition. General dictation, such as Google's, where you theoretically can say anything is different from more rudimentary variants where you build a vocabulary for the application to compare to (you know what words you're exactly looking for). I think that most open source implementations are of the latter kind, so if that's what you're looking for it ought to be easier than finding a general dictation implementation.

Comment: Very good point. No, our scenario is way simpler than general dictation: we are just looking for recognition of a strict set of words and sentences. So it's more a comparison than proper recognition. Any hint in this sense?

Answer (score 2):

I've had pretty good result for a general dictation application using the HTTP API from Nuance (https://developer.nuance.com/public/index.php?task=prodDev).

Basically we built a websocket server (you'd probably use SignalR in .NET) that we connected to from the browser (you can't hit the Nuance API directly due to security issues with chunked encoding) and had our websocket server act as a proxy that passed the data from the client on to Nuance. Nuance then returned a string interpretation of what was said which we then returned to the client.

It was pretty accurate most of the time, though YMMV. :) We also had to go through a manual approval process and describe our use case, which isn't a big deal but good to know.

Comment: Thanks Oskar. By Nuance you mean that recognition is hosted on their servers, or a server application sold by Nuance?

Comment: It looks like we would end up relying on Nuance's cloud. This would unfortunately just shift our dependence from a provider to another - unless I am missing something

Comment: Yeah, you'd be dependent on their infrastructure. You'd avoid the dependency on WebkitSpeechRecognition though, so it wouldn't matter what client you ran, as long as it supports webkit (and audio input, of course).

Comment: It should say websockets in my previous comment, not webkit.. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are good server-side solutions based on open source speech recognition engines like CMUSphinx or Kaldi, however, server must run under Linux, not Win. You might be able to run Win server, but you have to port Linux solution to it.

To try how it works you can visit http://kaljurand.github.io/dictate.js

Comment: Thanks, trying that. Do you have any direct experience with it, and if so do you think it's scalable / reliable enough for use in a commercial product?